# Replace four last characters in a string

Tags: javascript, replace, filenames

I want to replace the four last characters of an image.

**Q1)**

I want this:

```
http://domain.com/image1.jpg
http://domain.com/image2.png
http://domain.com/image3.gif
```

to become:

```
http://domain.com/image1-big.jpg
http://domain.com/image2-big.png
http://domain.com/image3-big.gif
```

**Q2)**

And then I want to be able to do the opposite way (removing -big from the file name)

Any suggestions for Q1 and Q2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = 'http://domain.com/image1.jpg';

// Embiggen
str.replace(/\.(gif|png|jpg)$/, '-big.$1');

// Unbiggen
str.replace(/-big\.(gif|png|jpg)$/, '.$1');
```

It's a bit naive, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks Alex! Is it a efficient way to do it (I am planning to do it on quite a lot of images).

Comment: Short regular expression replacements on short strings in a highly optimized operation in modern JS engines.  According to JSperf.com, this snippet runs at about 1.4 million times per second: http://jsperf.com/isregexsupafast Is that fast enough?

Comment: Hehe thats fast enough. Thanks for explaning :D